# Howto disable nuget machine-wide cache?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

As you know NuGet uses %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache location for caching. It first checks if requested packages is here then download if needed.

**How can I properly disable this cache mechanism from Nuget and "Visual Studio 2013", and make sure they always download from sources?**

Can I build Nuget Package Manager Extension from source, then install it to Visual Studio? Or Are there any registry configuration that disable it?

Thanks

Comment: As someone with a 100GB nuget cache on his machine, I'd like to know this too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable NuGet from using a cache. The only thing you can do without changing the source code is to change the location of the cache directory using a NuGetCachePath environment variable.

So you are left with clearing the local cache manually or automatically before installing a NuGet package or modifying the source code for NuGet's Visual Studio extension.

The source code for NuGet 2.8.5 and older is available on [CodePlex](http://nuget.codeplex.com/).

The source code for NuGet 3.0 is available on GitHub

There are some [instructions](http://docs.nuget.org/Contribute/Setting-up-the-NuGet-Development-Environment) available on how to setup the NuGet development environment to be able to build and run NuGet within Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, I will choose to recompile nuget package manager from sources.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's possible to do so in case you'd running Install NuGet packages task through `CLI` which is common practice.

You can order `NuGet` to not use it's cache at all by using `-NoCache` input parameter. Then it will behave as you described. See [CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) of `NuGet.exe`