# Using paket offline

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, paket

Is it possible to use **paket** having no connection to *Nuget* repository? We have our *nuget* repository where we store all necessary libs. We use **paket** to fetch it. Everything works fine while we are working under our company network or using vpn. However **paket** fails to reach our *nuget* repository outside our network. No doubts, this behavior is expected.

At the same time I noticed that **paket** tries to fetch packages from local *nuget* cache (%userprofile%.nuget) first. The desired behavior is to work directly with *nuget* local cache if there is no connection to original *nuget* repository and to throw just warning about it, not an error (throw an error only if there is no required package in cache). Is it possible or such functionality is not provided (yet)? As I know *Nuget* doesn't crash build if it can get packages from the local cache without connection to repository. Thanks

UPD [Howto disable nuget machine-wide cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557893/howto-disable-nuget-machine-wide-cache) - that is not what I want. *Nuget* itself works fine, the question is about **paket.exe**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto disable nuget machine-wide cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557893/howto-disable-nuget-machine-wide-cache)

Comment: Have you read this section: Paket - Additional Caches https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/caches.html

Comment: @Kiliman this is exactly  what I need! Thanks! Have no idea how I couldn't notice this page in documentation...

Comment: Maybe [paket.local](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/local-file.html) is a better way nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

`NuGet cache` is folder mostly located in `Users\{CurrentUser}\Local\NuGet\Cache` and stores data from network searches and downloaded packages before they're copied into your `packages` folder.

What you're probably looking for is `local repository`, e.g. any folder available in your filesystem. You can even combine it with network repositories and so it will work both online and offline.

`paket.dependencies` content:

```
source C:\MyLocalFeed
source \\my.domain\networkFolderFeed
source source https://nuget.org/api/v2
```

There are no further requirements on structure of folder you're going to use as repository. Only thing you need is to place there your *.nupkg files.

Answer (score 0):

I just have a hard time making paket to work offline, so I think this question deserves an answer.

> At the same time I noticed that paket tries to fetch packages from
>   local nuget cache (%userprofile%.nuget) first

Your observation is correct. From my experience, just put the requested libs in `%USERPROFILE%/.nuget/packages`, then do a `.paket\paket.exe restore`.
 It will work.

Do note that we need to use **Nuget packages**; eg: copied from another computer `.nuget` folder, or generated when you are connected. **DO NOT** copy paket `packages` folder because it won't work.